# Cannot save credentials

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm trying to save the credentials using code like this:

```
$user = "test@mail.ru"
$password = Get-Content pass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$password

Send-MailMessage -To test@mail.ru -Subject Test -Body Check -SmtpServer smtp.domen.ru -From test@mail.ru -Credential $credentials
```

Now when you run the PowerShell script - generates a form input password "Windows PowerShell credentials request". How to get rid of this query, because the credentials are stored?

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The code you posted doesn't save credentials, it reads an already saved password from a file and builds a `PSCredential` object from a mail address and that password. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to do, and what exactly doesn't work as you expect. If you get errors: update your question with the full error messages.

Comment: Well,I'll try another way, I have Powershell startup scripts issue the authorization form. This window must be removed. Here:

Comment: `$Credentials` is empty, so the cmdlet prompts you for credentials since you called it with the parameter `-Credential`. As for why the variable is empty: you'll have to show your actual code for us to find out the reason. It's quite obviously different from the code you posted here.

Comment: As well, if the code that is higher than I saved credentials in variable $credentials? They can not be empty .All right, the second part of the script is send mail cmdlets send-mail-message, there I just have a variable $credentials. Share? Now, I lay out.

Comment: `Send-MailMessage -To test@mail.ru -Subject Test -Body Check -SmtpServer smtp.domen.ru -From test@mail.ru -Credential $credentials`

Comment: If `-Credential $Credentials` produces a credentials dialog, then the variable is empty. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31808727/edit) your question and show the actual (complete) code. Showing bits and pieces isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: Well! How, then, to write data into a variable? I only Have two parts in of the script, if it's so important, unite

Comment: Yes, seeing the actual code that causes your problem as well as any error that this exact code throws is *very* important for finding out what's going wrong. Does `pass.txt` actually contain the text representation of a `SecureString` object? Also, either `ConvertTo-SecureString` or `New-Object` should be throwing an error. What is it?

Comment: pass.txt is a text file which contains the encrypted password. I pull out and transform back into a secure string for use in the parameter-Сredential.

Comment: Does echoing `$password` display `System.Security.SecureString`? Does `$credentials.GetNetworkCredentials().Password` display the correct password?

Comment: I do not understand, it can be said in other words, the password is correct,  I have to manually send mail.

Comment: Please answer the questions. Does `$password = Get-Content pass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString; $password` display the text `System.Security.SecureString`? Does `$password = Get-Content pass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString; $credentials = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential 'foo',$password; $credentials.GetNetworkCredentials().Password` display the actual password?

Comment: 1)Yes of course.2)Yes

Comment: Then you must have mistyped the variable name in your `Send-MailMessage` statement. Otherwise it's not possible you got a credentials prompt from it.

Comment: Don't understand, I think the problem is in the syntax, have tried variations on msdn, the fact that the parameter -Credential automatically calls the authorization window.

Comment: Again, it ***only*** does that when you pass an ***empty*** argument to the parameter.